# Error in Connecting to Oracle Database by a JSP page on OAS 10g

Tags: database, oracle, jsp

i am using Oracle Application server 10.1.2.0.2. I am trying to connect an oracle database with a jsp login page.. which will later on redirect to a form. For now i am just trying to connect my page with the database.

My "connect.jsp" is in directory "C:\DevSuiteHome2\forms\j2ee\formsapp\formsweb"

I can access jsp files via http://p---w0--4.lo-----a.com:8889/forms/helloworld.jsp [working jsp file]

Source code of connect.jsp:

`<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>`
`<HTML>`
`<HEAD>`
`<TITLE>Simple JSP/Oracle Query Example</TITLE>`
`</HEAD>`
`<BODY>`

`<%`

`Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");`

`Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@p---w0--4.lo---a.com:8889:xii", "i----er", "i----er");`
                        `// @//machineName:port:SID,   userid,  password`

`%>`
`</BODY>`
`</HTML>`

now when i try to visit: http://p---w0--4.lo-----a.com:8889/forms/connect.jsp it gives the following errors:

500 Internal Server Error
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Bad packet type    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:137)   at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:174)   at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:286)   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:327)   at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:433)    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:150)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:31)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:571)   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:512) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:171) at _loginbox._check1._jspService(_check1.java:50)   [SRC:/LOGINBOX/check1.jsp:12]   at com.orionserver[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.0.2)].http.OrionHttpJspPage.service(OrionHttpJspPage.java:56)  at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageTable.service(JspPageTable.java:350) at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.internalService(JspServlet.java:509) at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:413) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853) at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.0.2)].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:824)  at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.0.2)].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:330) at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.0.2)].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:830)  at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.0.2)].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:285) at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.0.2)].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:126) at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.0.2)].util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:186)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:534)

Your response would be highly appreciated. I am a beginner so pardon some newbie questions

Comment: Why are you putting `html` tags in your `page` directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response, but it was my mistake. I was passing in the wrong host as the parameter. The code I have above is correct to connect to an Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you should do

```
<html>
   <head> 
      <title>Simple JSP/Oracle Query Example</title> 
   </head> 
   <body>
<%
     Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//your_host_name_or_your_ip:1521/your_database_name", "user", "password");
     System.out.println("Is connection equal to null");
     System.out.println(conn == null);
%>
   </body>
</html>
```

You can check [this](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC) for the appropriate url to use.
Let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: THanks for ur response, but it was my mistake I was passing wrong host as the parameter. Code I have typed is correct to connect to database.